# UIView subclass not receiving touchesBegan, touchesEnded

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview

Ok- so I have an application which subclasses UIView, and relies on touchesBegan and touchesEnded. I refer of course to these callbacks:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

I updated my iOS from 7 to 9 just the other day (I know, I'm lazy) to find that the touches aren't working. Turns out the above functions aren't getting called in my UIView subclass. Curious, I started a blank project, which is short enough that I'll just post the code here.

main.m:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Here's AppDelegate. Create a window and a view dynamically.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "SubView.h"

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    //create a window and give it a frame. makeKeyAndVisible
    CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    self.window.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    //Create a subview. Make it a red square. make sure it has a background.
    //set the userInteractionEnabled and multipleTouchEnabled and for
    //good meausure call becomeFirstResponder.
    SubView *view = [[SubView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,100,100)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.window addSubview:view];
    view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    view.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
    [view becomeFirstResponder];


    //Create default UIViewControllers because Objective-C fails if the windows don't have
    //root view controllers. I don't like being muscled into MVC but what are you gonna do
    NSArray *windows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
    for(UIWindow *window in windows) {
        if(window.rootViewController == nil){
            UIViewController* vc = [[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
            window.rootViewController = vc;
            window.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            window.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
        }
    }

return YES;
}

@end
```

And here's the SubView class. Does just has the touchesBegan touchesEnded.

SubView.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface SubView : UIView {
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

@end
```

SubView.m

```
#import "SubView.h"

@implementation SubView

//delegate method for touches began
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    //[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    NSLog(@"touchesBegan!");

}


//delegate method for touches ending.
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    //[super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    NSLog(@"touchesEnded!");
}

//just for good measure.
- (BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Pretty simple. Create a window, create a SubView, add SubView to the window, set userInteractionEnabled. And yet, it doesn't work. I've looked at the following S.O. posts:

[subviews are not receiving touches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873167/subviews-are-not-receiving-touches)

[iPhone SDK - Forwarding touches from a UIViewController to a subview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599103/iphone-sdk-forwarding-touches-from-a-uiviewcontroller-to-a-subview)

[touchesBegan not responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307017/touchesbegan-not-responding)

[touchesBegan in UIView not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412101/touchesbegan-in-uiview-not-being-called)

[touchesBegan not called in UIView subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443177/touchesbegan-not-called-in-uiview-subclass)

[touchesBegan not called in a UIView subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061239/touchesbegan-not-called-in-a-uiview-subclass)

They all say userInteractionEnabled = YES should fix it, or there might be view covering another view, or the view might have a transparent background. None of that applies here. I've set view.userInteractionEnabled = YES, and I've even tried to give the view first-responder status. None of it seems to do any good.

Astute observers will also see that I'm setting these values on the window itself:

```
window.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
window.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
```

I've tried it with and without. No dice. I've tried calling

```
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event]
```

and

```
[super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event]
```

in those callbacks on SubView. No dice. Any help you can give me would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: do you even see the SubView?

Comment: Same question. Adding views directly to your window is deeply dodgy behaviour; adding a view and then adding a view controller on top later probably just ensures that your view is obscured.

Comment: add view to view controller not window

Comment: Yes, I see the UIView just fine. A nice red square.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at your view hierarchy while the app is running, either using `recursiveDescription` or using Xcode 7's “Debug View Hierarchy” button.

```
(lldb) po [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
<UIWindow: 0x7fc1f9d17b20; frame = (0 0; 414 736); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fc1f9d18910>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x7fc1f9d16560>>
   | <SubView: 0x7fc1f9c04350; frame = (100 100; 100 100); layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc1f9c04730>>
   | <UIView: 0x7fc1f9c07500; frame = (0 0; 414 736); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc1f9c07fc0>>
```

Views later in the list of subviews are “closer” to the screen and thus receives touches first. The view created by the generic `UIViewController` fills the window and is in front of your `SubView`. Thus your `SubView` can't receive touches.

Apple added the `rootViewController` property to `UIWindow` in iOS 4.0—over five years ago. By fighting it, you're only making trouble for yourself. Just let `rootViewController.view` be the single top-level view in your window, and add your subviews under that. Nobody's forcing you to add any other view controllers to your app.

Comment: Perfect. Adding this [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:view]; and removing this [self.window addSubview:view]; solved the problem. I will fight no longer.